# Compressing section numbers without repeating chapter number in references

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I want to compress numbers of sections in a reference, but without repeating the chapter number, while maintaining full functionality of of `hyperref` and `\ref`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{intro}
I want the hyperref functionallity and automated references of 
\ref{sec:chap3sec3}--\ref{sec:chap3sec5}; 
but the look of 3.3--5. 
\ref{sec:chap3sec3}--\hyperref[sec:chap3sec5]{5} does half of what I want, 
but I don't know how to get the section number without chapter number.

\chapter{two}
\chapter{three}
\section{chap3sec1}
\section{chap3sec2}
\section{chap3sec3}\label{sec:chap3sec3}
\section{chap3sec4}
\section{chap3sec5}\label{sec:chap3sec5}

\end{document}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Would using `cleveref` be an option?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: `\crefrange{eq1}{eq5}` is typeset as `Eqs.~(1.1) to~(1.5)` according to the manual; `\crefrangelabelformat` allows to change the `to~`, but not the individual labels. Unless I missed something in the manual `cleveref` is no help.

Comment: I second Gonzalo's suggestion that you consider using the cleveref package and its `\crefrange` command. All sections in your document are numbered with the respective chapter number prefixed to the the section numbers, right? If that's the case, I think you're risking creating *a lot* of confusion among your readers if you omit the chapter number prefix from some of the section numbers used in a cross-reference. "Sections 3.3--3.5" is unambiguous, though not all that elegant. Do you want your readers to puzzle, however briefly, over whether "Sections 3.3--5" means "Section 3.3 to Chapter 5"?

Comment: @Mico: Given the context I use it in (outline of the MSc thesis, effectively an inline list) "3.3--5" is clear, so I would prefer it as asked.

Comment: @MarkusSchmassmann -- Both clarity and ambiguity are in the eye of the beholder, right? I must confess that I don't know how to implement the formatting requirement you've set out -- at least not within the framework of the `cleveref` package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LaTeX only stores the complete reference number. To get the section part of the number,
the reference first needs to be extracted. Then the chapter part before the first dot
can be stripped:

```
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\stripref}[1]{%
  \refused{#1}%
  \begingroup
    \edef\x{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{}{\noexpand\textbf{??}}}%
    \hyperref[{#1}]{%
      \expandafter\stripref@aux\x.\@nil
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\def\stripref@aux#1.#2\@nil{%
  \ifx\\#2\\%
    #1%
  \else
    \stripref@dot#2\@nil
  \fi
}
\def\stripref@dot#1.\@nil{#1}
\makeatother
```

Usage: `\ref{sec:chap3sec3}--\stripref{sec:chap3sec5}`